# Переменная в имени переменной. Bash.

Tags: bash, linux

Всем привет. Столкнулся с таким вопросом. Скажем есть скрипт:

```
#!/bin/bash

var1=blabla
${${var1}_ext}=onetwo

echo ${${var1}_ext}
```

С таким раскладом выдается сообщение, что

```
blabla_ext=onetwo: command not found
```

И теперь вопрос: есть ли вообще возможность использовать что-то подобное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот обсуждалось, гляньте:
http://pgl.yoyo.org/bits/tech/bash-variable-variables/100:2008-12-05/

Пример взят по ссылке.

```
[mimi:pgl]:~ $ tits=arse
[mimi:pgl]:~ $ arse=cheese
[mimi:pgl]:~ $ echo ${!tits}
cheese
[mimi:pgl]:~ $ eval echo $`echo $tits`
cheese
```

Comment: Спасибо. Помогло