# Переменная в переменной BASH CGI

Tags: linux, postgresql, bash, shell, cgi

Имеется скрипт:

```
NAME=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | sed -n 's/^.*name=\([^&]*\).*$/\1/p' | sed "s/%20/ /g"`
RES=`psql -U user -d db -t -c "SELECT tabl FROM tablica WHERE name = '$NAME'"`
echo $RES
```

Все работает прекрасно (GET запросы идут нормально).
Но вот данные из базы не идут.
А проблема в том, что значение параметра NAME в запросе WHERE как такого нет.
И проблема в том, что написан неправильный синтаксис.
Я уже перечитал много статей в Интернете, но про переменную в переменной с обратными кавычками нет ничего.
Помогите с синтаксисом.

P.S. Просьба не пересылать меня [на этот вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150301/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-bash). Он все равно неправильный.

Comment: `WHERE name = ' \`eval ${NAME}\` ' " \`

Comment: Все равно не работает. Наверное опять проблема с кавычками.

Comment: С обратными кавычками как будто бы всё нормально. Если значение $NAME пустое, то это скорее всего из-за того, что регулярка в первом sed не срабатывает.

Comment: А точно, там вроде не работают рекурсивные backticks, попробуй скобки с долларом вместо них поставить как-то так. `$(echo "hello$(echo "world")")`

Comment: Делаю так localhost/index.sh?name=post1 вот по аргументу post1 как бы он и должен делать выборку в базе. но через просто echo он выводится, а в psql нет.

Comment: @Аноним Если через echo выводится, а в psql нет, то единственное, что можно предложить - это экранировать обратным слэшом двойные кавычки, в которые заключён SELECT.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы выполняете скрипт в **bash** то заключая `$NAME` в *одинарные* кавычки Вы исключаете *подстановку переменной*, т.е в скрипте используется не значение переменной `NAME`, а просто текстовая строка из 5 символов: `$, N, A, M, E`.

Comment: Кроме тех случаев, когда строка, заключённая в одинарные кавычки, заключена ещё и в двойные.