# Переменная в имени переменной

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт, который получает на входе имя устройства, например, switch, номер 
 порта. Нужно, чтобы он на выходе, создавал переменную с именем 
 `${var^^}_PORT(например, SWITCH_PORT)` и задавал ее значение, равное $1

```
port=$1
var=$2
var1=var2
var2=$(echo ${var^^})"_PORT"
`echo ${!var1}`=$port
```

Но при выполнении скрипта получаю SWITCH_PORT=2: command not found

Что я делаю не так?

Видел это: [Переменная в имени переменной. Bash.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/150301/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-bash)
Сделал как написано, но не работает.

Comment: а зачем поставили "`"  в последней строке? уберите их и все заработает

Comment: `declare ${var^^}_PORT=$port` проверяем `echo $SWITCH_PORT`

Comment: Читать `help declare` или соответствующую часть `man bash`

Answer (score 2):

в вопросе неясность, поэтому отвечу на все три варианта.

#### вариант 1.

нужно, чтобы скрипт выводил в *stdout* строку вида `y_port=x`, где вместо `x` подставлялся бы первый переданный скрипту параметр, а вместо `y` — второй.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $2_port=$1
```

проверка:

```
$ ./script 2 switch
switch_port=2
```

#### вариант 2.

нужно, чтобы внутри скрипта (*для последующего использования внутри этого же скрипта*) создавалась переменная с именем `y_port` со значением `x` (смысл `x` и `y` тот же самый, что и в первом варианте), и это же имя сохранялось в другой переменной `z`, и можно было бы получить значение `x`, оперируя лишь переменной `z`.

```
#!/bin/bash
z=$2_port
export $z=$1
# последующее использование
echo "значение переменной с именем $z равно ${!z}"
```

проверка:

```
$ ./script 2 switch
значение переменной с именем switch_port равно 2
```

#### вариант 3.

скрипту передаётся параметр вида `y=x`, нужно создать внутри скрипта переменную `y` со значением `x`, а имя этой перменной сохранить в переменной `z`, чтобы можно было получить значение `x`, оперируя лишь переменной `z`.

```
#!/bin/bash
export $1
z=${1%%=*}
# последующее использование
echo "значение переменной с именем $z равно ${!z}"
```

проверка:

```
$ ./script foo=bar
значение переменной с именем foo равно bar
```

Comment: Оба ваши варианты рабочие, но, мне затем, нужно, чтобы далее в скрипте, выполнилась команда: conmmand switch_port=2, но я не знаю, какое будет значение $2 и $1, то есть, как мне подставить в команду conmmand $2_port=$1

Comment: т.е., параметр, с которым выполняется ваш скрипт — один. и равен (к примеру) `switch_port=2`. и вам внутри скрипта нужно обращаться к переменной `switch_port`, и это имя вам внутри скрипта известно. правильно я понял?

Comment: Разобрался. Спасибо за вашу помощь. Очень помогло. Моя ошибка в применении ваших рекомендаций была в том, что мне надо несколько раз использовать полученную переменную, но ее достаточно 1 раз экспортировать и пользуйся - не хочу )

Comment: я внёс и третий вариант. а вопрос вы, пожалуйста, сформулируйте точнее: что передаётся, что требуется получить.